# Running a process in a specified time window

Tags: cron, kill, scheduling

Large computational tasks consume time and computational resources, therefore I am looking for a way to execute them in a specified time window using a shell script.

I want to run the script `batch.sh` during idle hours (2AM-6AM) and continue on the following day from where it left off.

Right now I'm using a combination of three one-line commands, is it possible to fully automate the time scheduling?

The original script that starts `luajit` with caffeinate:

```
caffeinate -i ./batch.sh
```

Command to pause the script (should run at 6AM):

```
kill -TSTP `pgrep luajit | cut -d' ' -f2`
```

Command to resume the script (should run at 2AM):

```
kill -CONT `pgrep luajit | cut -d' ' -f2`
```